# Sending memorystream via mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                PrintableComponentLink pcl = new PrintableComponentLink(new PrintingSystem());
                pcl.Component = ASPxGridViewExporter1;
                pcl.Margins.Left = pcl.Margins.Right = 50;
                pcl.Landscape = true;
                pcl.CreateDocument(false);
                pcl.PrintingSystem.Document.AutoFitToPagesWidth = 1;
                pcl.ExportToPdf(ms);

MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
            mailMsg.To.Add("n@x.net");


            MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress("info@x.net");
            mailMsg.From = mailAddress;


            mailMsg.Subject = "";
            mailMsg.Body = "";

            System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, "x.pdf");



            mailMsg.Attachments.Add(attach);


            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("192.168.1.200", 25);
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);

            ms.Close();
```

And I am getting 153B file in attachment.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Wrap `pcl` in a `using` statement, and after it's done, make sure `ms` is flushed and reset to be ready to read.

Comment: @TimS. same problem is with "using"...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `ms.Position = 0` before attaching the stream will take care of it.

Less likely, but possible not closing/disposing stream will be needed (but I don't think it is the case of synchronous sending of the mail).

Side note: I'd have separate `MemoryStream` for writing and reading/sending. Just creating read-only stream over buffer of original stream will make code cleaner/easier to reason about. Sample below, also its better to use other constructor that takes buffer+length instead of copy:

```
   var streamToSend = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass your MemoryStream and ContentType to your attachment, not the Memorystream and PDF name.  Also make sure ms is set to position 0.

Try replacing these lines

```
System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, "x.pdf");
mailMsg.Attachments.Add(attach);
```

With the following:

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct= new System.Net.Mime.ContentType();
ct.MediaType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;
ct.Name = "x.pdf";

Attachment attach = new Attachment(ms, contentType);
mailMsg.Attachments.Add(attach);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a MemoryStream as an Attachment.  [ExportToPdf](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingLinkBase_ExportToPdftopic1199) accepts types derived from Stream.  Instead, export the PDF to a `FileStream`.

`pcl.ExportToPdf(fileStream);`

Then Attach the FileStream and correct MIME type:

`var attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(fileStream, "x.pdf", MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);`

Just delete the temp file it will create in the process.  For whatever reason MemoryStream does not work for attachments here even if you set the `MemoryStream.Position = 0;`